# what is the best way to consume daba of a database in a silverlight RIA

Tags: c#, silverlight, ado.net, silverlight-4.0

I'm building a software using silverlight 4 RIA enabled. The question is I don't know what is the best way to consume data from a MS SQL SERVER. 
The best way of consuming data might mean the following:

1. the code is clean
2. the development time is quick
3. maintenance is quick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RIA Services is the fastest way to develop database apps in Silverlight.
http://www.silverlight.net/getstarted/riaservices/

IF your app is RIA Services enabled, it's as easy as:

1. Create Entity Framework Model for your database
2. Add new Domain Service for the model
3. Drag and drop Data Sources onto your Silverlight UI from VS "Data Sources"
4. You're done.